# How to write a GET SQL Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, api, rest, stored-procedures, get

I'm trying to make a Rest API in Visual Studio 2012 using ASP.NET MVC 4.

So, right now I'm trying to make an SQL Procedure for GET and POST methods. 
I have little experience with SQL so I really need some help.

( I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio )

Right now I'm trying to make a procedure that tells me the values of every row's "A", "B", "C", and "D" columns. This would be helpful for my GET method in my API, where I plan to loop through the number of rows the table has!

The problem right now is SQL won't accept Select top @counter, it will accept Select top 10 or some actual number.

How do I fix this? Also, is there an easier way of doing what I'm trying to do? 
I feel this is likely not the most efficient way to write a procedure for a simple GET Api.

```
Create Procedure GetHotTicketEvent (@counter INTEGER, @A bigint out, @B bigint out, @C varchar(500) out, @D int out)

AS

BEGIN

Select top @counter A From myTable 
EXCEPT 
Select top @counter-1 A From myTable

Select top  @counter B From myTable
EXCEPT 
Select top @counter-1 B From myTable

Select top @counter C From myTable
EXCEPT 
Select top @counter-1 C From myTable

Select top @counter D From myTable
EXCEPT 
Select top @counter-1 D From myTable

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
declare @cnt int = 2
declare @Account varchar(1000)

select top(@cnt) @Account = col1
FROM  ( VALUES ('A',5),
               ('K',3),
               ('B',8),
               ('B',10),
               ('A',12) )tc(col1, col2) 

select @Account --results K
```